# Series Expansion of $(e^{(-\lambda/\mu_A}) \mu_A)/ (E_{-k_1} (\lambda/\mu_A))$ at $\lambda \to \infty$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I would like to find the series expansion of 
$$\mu_A\frac{e^{-\lambda/\mu_A} }{ E_{-k_1} (\lambda/\mu_A)} \quad \text{as} \,\, \lambda \to \infty$$
. Mathematica calculates it as: $\lambda - k_1 \mu_A + (k_1 \mu_A^2)/\lambda$ but I cannot validate it. $E_{-k_1} (\lambda/\mu_A)$ is the exponential integral.

I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: own thoughts???

Comment: btw. the parameter $\mu_A$ is irrelevant as long as $|\mu_a|>0$ in this context. You are looking for $\lim_{a\rightarrow\pm\infty}$ where $a=\lambda/\mu_A$

Comment: From this website http://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html                 I know that the asymptotic expansion of $E_{-k_1}(\lambda/ \mu)$ truncated at the first degree is: $\frac{e^{-\lambda/ \mu} \mu_A}{\lambda}$       However, Mathematica tells me that series expansion of $\frac{1}{E_{-k_1}(\lambda/ \mu)}$ is $e^{-\lambda/ \mu} (\frac{\lambda}{\mu_A}-k_1+\frac{k_1 \mu_A}{\lambda})$.

Comment: Working from the mathematica output it is easy to get to $\lambda-k_1 \mu_A+\frac{k_1 \mu_A^2}{\lambda}$. However, I do not know how to get the series expansion of $\frac{1}{E_{-k_1}(\lambda/ \mu)}$

Comment: $e^{-\lambda/ \mu} (\frac{\lambda}{\mu_A}-k_1+\frac{k_1 \mu_A}{\lambda})$ should be  $e^{\lambda/ \mu} (\frac{\lambda}{\mu_A}-k_1+\frac{k_1 \mu_A}{\lambda})$